# Alternative to dcs.gif

Tags: webtrends

In `Webtrends` calls to `WebTrends.multiTrack` are logged using `dcs.gif`.  Is there a way to tell `Webtrends` to use `Javascript` instead of `dcs.gif` to do the tracking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, multiTrack *is* JavaScript.  If you are using the onDemand Webtrends service, or if you have version 9 of the SDC server for OnPremise, you can use the DCSAPI service, which uses POST instead of GET for the server calls.  Servers are not required to respond to POST, so you do not need a round trip, as you do with GET.

[Data Collection API](http://product.webtrends.com/DCAPI/sw/index.html)

This method is designed for usage with non-browser applications, such as mobile apps; but, of course, it will work anywhere you wish to use it.